# libvips Nearest Neighbor / Bicubic Deep Zoom Pyramid Creation

Tags: python, image-processing, deepzoom, vips

I'm in the process of moving some of my code off of openzoom.py and onto Libvips but am not sure how dictate the interpolation method, which is important. I at the very least need to be able to use bicubic/bilinear in one case and nearest neighbors in the other case.

My old code is as follows:

```
creator = deepzoom.ImageCreator(tile_size=128, tile_overlap=2, tile_format="png",
                                        image_quality=0.8, resize_filter="nearest")
creator.create(sourceFile, destFile)
```

Currently, using pyvips I have the following

```
image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sourceFile)
image.dzsave(destFile, tile_size=128, overlap=2,
                     suffix='.png[Q=80]')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, [dzsave](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/VipsForeignSave.html#vips-dzsave) will average each 2x2 block of pixels, which is equivalent to bilinear.

Sometimes, for example with images where pixel values represent labels rather than intensity, you need a non-interpolatory downsize. For these cases, you can use the `region_shrink` parameter to select `median` or `mode`, which will both preserve label values.

I would use:

```
image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sourceFile, access='sequential')
image.dzsave(destFile,
             overlap=1,
             tile_size=126,
             region_shrink='mode',
             suffix='.png')
```

Don't forget to set the `access` hint. It'll give you a huge improvement in speed and memory behaviour for large images that don't support random access.

The PNG Q number sets quantization quality when outputting palettized images. [Perhaps you mean `compression`](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/VipsForeignSave.html#vips-pngsave)? libvips defaults to 6, the PNG standard.

Are you sure you want `overlap=2`? The deepzoom standard is overlap 1. Overlap 1 means there is one pixel extra around the edge of every tile, so tiles in the centre of the image will share two pixels on every edge with their neighbours. Setting `overlap=2` means you'll have four pixel overlaps, confusingly.

Likewise, `tile_size=128` means most of your tiles will be 132x132 pixels. It doesn't matter for PNG, but JPG works best with multiples of 8 on an axis. I would set `tile_size` to (128 - 2 * overlap), as deepzoom does by default.

git master libvips adds `max`, `min` and `nearest` (always pick the top-left pixel) as well. A branch has `lanczos3`, but it was never merged for various reasons.

Comment: Thank you! This is precisely what I needed to do, and I appreciate you catching my other mistakes :)